# What is a proper gitignore when using FireBase in Unity?

Tags: git, firebase, unity-game-engine, github, gitignore

I have been googling this without any luck, the little results i found don't address the file hierarchy i am dealing with in my project.
So i have a simple unity project and BEFORE i use FireBase the folder hierarchy looks like this:

```
Assets  
---->Scenes  
Packages
```

After importing FireBase the hierarchy looks like this:

```
Assets  
---->Editor Default Resources  
---->ExternalDependencyManager  
---->FireBase  
---->Parse  
---->Plugins  
---->Scenes  
---->StreamingAssets  
Packages
```

Any idea what should i change in my .gitignore to avoid all those hundreds of megabytes from being added to my github?

My current gitignore:

```
# This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory
#
# Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore
#
[Ll]ibrary/
[Tt]emp/
[Oo]bj/
[Bb]uild/
[Bb]uilds/
[Ll]ogs/
[Uu]ser[Ss]ettings/

# MemoryCaptures can get excessive in size.
# They also could contain extremely sensitive data
[Mm]emoryCaptures/

# Recordings can get excessive in size
[Rr]ecordings/

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# /[Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# Autogenerated Jetbrains Rider plugin
[Aa]ssets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.aab
*.unitypackage
*.app

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties

# Packed Addressables
[Aa]ssets/[Aa]ddressable[Aa]ssets[Dd]ata/*/*.bin*

# Temporary auto-generated Android Assets
[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa.meta
[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa/*
```

Comment: Those files are necessary for the operation of Firebase. You do not want to ignore hem.

Comment: Github doesn't allow to commit more than 100M in a single commit. this is an actual problem. i need FireBase

Comment: Make multiple commits.

Comment: How is that possible? the firebase package are imported all at once to my unity project

Comment: Stage half the files, commit, stage the rest, commit.

Comment: There a single file located in Assets\Firebase\Plugins\x86_64\FirebaseCppApp-8_8_0.so that is of size 120MB. Is there a way of committing it?

Comment: Github recommends using LFS for that. https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github

Comment: So all the devs using FireBase have to go through LFS to use github? Isn't there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Retired Ninja in the op comments, you don't want to ignore the Firebase packages, since your project requires Firebase to run. The same goes for any asset packages you may have installed in the Unity project.

That is unless you have some other package manager to install dependencies, and then you could git ignore the package files. However, I don't believe there is an npm-style package manager for Unity that has been widely adopted yet, so to ensure your project builds, maintains consistent meta files, package versions, etc., just run the following in git bash before commiting:

```
git lfs track "Assets/Firebase/Plugins/x86_64/FirebaseCppApp-11_6_0.bundle
git lfs track "Assets/Firebase/Plugins/x86_64/FirebaseCppApp-11_6_0.so
```

Depending on the version, the "11_6_0" part will change.

Comment: Why make it so complicated? Use a wildcard: `git lfs track *firebase*.bundle`, `git lfs track *firebase*.so`

Answer (score -1):

you can add the following lines in your gitignore for firebase
Basically, put the directory which you don't want to commit in the following way:

```
/[Ff]older/directorytobeignored/

[Ff]older => This folder lies in the same directory as your Assets folder.
```

Like this:

```
/[Aa]ssets/Editor Default Resources/

/[Aa]ssets/ExternalDependencyManager/

/[Aa]ssets/Firebase/

/[Aa]ssets/Parse/

/[Aa]ssets/Plugins/
```